# Django UniqueConstraint usecase

Tags: django, django-models, unique-constraint

I have the model users and Address with the Address model containing the user as a Foreign key. Is it possible to handle this use case with constraints that in case of multiple users addresses a user can have one default address? Here is a sample code.
Thank you.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    blank=False,
    null=False,
    related_name="user_address", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'active'],
                                condition=models.Q(active=True),
                                name='user default address.')
        ]
```

Comment: how exactly do you set which is default address, and what is wrong with your current UniqueConstraint

Comment: I want to set the default address by marking the active field only on one address and left it unchecked for all other user addresses. With the current UniqueConstraint it is not working and allowing multiple addresses to be marked as active.

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust your [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) slightly

```
  constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user'],
                                condition=models.Q(active=True),
                                name='unique_active_address')
        ]
```

---

EDIT:
Seems you are using MySQL and as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/indexes/#condition)

> The condition argument is ignored with MySQL and MariaDB as neither
> supports conditional indexes.

You cannot enforce this on database level with unique Index on MySQL as it does not support conditional indexes

Comment: I have tried it this way too already but it is not working.

Comment: did you migrate database? constraints are database enforced

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. Are you talking about Django migrations or MySQL constraints?

Comment: You have to makemigrations/migrate afterwards

Comment: Done that too. Tried different combinations of it. But it is not working for me. Have you tried it?

Comment: I just now seen you are using MySQL ? edited my answer

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am using MySQL. Are there any issues with MySQL?

Comment: Yes there are no conditional indexes on MySQL as my edit suggests, you will have to write business logic instead or migrate to supported database

Comment: Oh.Thanks. I forgot to verify that.